# How to start List of Figures numbering from 1 when the first figure is excluded

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, counters

I am writing my thesis and I have included a figure in the title page which i don't want to show up in the List of Figures. This is easily done but then the first figure in the main document is number 2 in the LoF like shown below:[image]

Is there a fix for this? I tried to look for a command that would reset/manipulate the Figure numbering but I didn't find one. I use `\listoffigures` to create the LoF and I print it after the input of the title page like this:

```
\begin{document}

\input{temp_titlepage.tex}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{acknowledgments.tex}
\clearpage

% print table of contents (ToC)
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

% list of figures
\listoffigures
```

I am sorry I don't include more code but it is very long and I don't think it will make a difference. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Simple solution: Do not use a caption if you don't need it. Just put the text `Figure: Title` below/above your figure.

Comment: @ TeXnician, the figure in the title page has no caption nor label

Comment: What for do you need a `figure` environment on a titlepage? Just use `\includegraphics` on its own.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance I didn't know I could have an image outside a `figure` environment. You can just post that as an answer since it worked, or erase the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LaTeX you include graphics using `\includegraphics`. If you need caption and label you either use `\captionof` or a `figure` environment (latter floats and therefore is better for automatic positioning).

However, for a picture on a titlepage it's mostly unnecessary to have a caption as you probably won't write a caption under your institution's logo, f.i. Hence you can just use `\includegraphics` without `figure` and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a need of a `figure` environment, use the `caption` package and its `\caption*` macro in order to generate the caption but prevent addition of entries to the `List of Figures`.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
    \caption*{The Duck}
  \end{figure}
\end{titlepage}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{Another duck}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```